# Filtering out empty files in azure-storage-azcopy sync

Tags: azure, shell, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azcopy

I am using azure-storage-azcopy sync to sync between source and destination.
This already works ok so far but often I receive empty files on source folder and that also gets copied to destination. How can I check and filter out blank/empty files and skip them from being copied to destination azure storage?

Below command is the one am using so far:

```
./azcopy sync "/sftp/sourceFolder" "https://mypersonal.blob.core.windows.net/payment" --recursive=false --include="PPP*.*.pgp"
```

Probably any shell script can also work but I have no idea on it how to achieve this.

Please help.

Comment: I would copy everything, as you do, and then delete the empty ones afterwards. Why is it so important, that you catch the empty files during copying?

Comment: what if you have some triggers on the destination bucket that triggers as soon as. any new file comes its way? not a good idea to give it empty file and keep triggering the processes unnecessarily

Comment: I guess you are not worried about the overhead of starting the triggers, but of the unnecessary noise they generate. In this case you could consider to put intelligence into the triggers to be silent on empty files. Yet another possibility would be to copy all files into a temp directory, and then loop over the files: Non-empty ones get moved into your destination bucket, and empty ones get deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I check and filter out blank/empty files and skip them from being copied to destination Azure storage?

AFAIK, there is no direct command to exclude empty files by size using **`azcopy sync`** command.

Instead, you can use the below shell script which creates an **`empty`** as folder and in the second line it filters empty files and moves the empty files to **`empty`** folder after moving you can able to sync between source and destination without empty files.

**`sync.sh`**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create empty folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p empty

# Move empty files from source folder to empty folder
find /sftp/sourceFolder -type f -empty -exec mv {} empty/ \;

# Sync files from source to destination
azcopy sync "/sftp/sourceFolder" "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/test/important" --recursive=false --include="PPP*.*.pgp"
```

**Output:**

```
venkatesxxx:~$ bash sync.sh
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.21.2 is available to download


Job 7b5bxxxxx has started
Log file is located at: /home/venkatesan/.azcopy/7b5be0dxxxxxx-21ded154cedc.log

0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 2 Pending, 2 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0

Job 7b5xxxx Summary
Files Scanned at Source: 2
Files Scanned at Destination: 1
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0667
Number of Copy Transfers for Files: 2
Number of Copy Transfers for Folder Properties: 0 
Total Number Of Copy Transfers: 2
Number of Copy Transfers Completed: 2
Number of Copy Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Deletions at Destination: 0
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 63
Total Number of Bytes Enumerated: 63
Final Job Status: Completed
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: thanks, although this answers the question asked but I would still like to get more insight on other possible and better options if we can acheieve with best possible performance

Comment: @jarvo69 I don't think any other possibility as of now either you need to delete empty files or move the empty file to another folder could be a possible way.

Comment: yeah these alternates I have in consdertion already but only 1 command seems be good to go if that only has to be the answer:

`find "SOURCE" -type f -not -empty -name "*.pgp" -exec sh -c 'basename="`basename "{}"`"; azcopy sync "{}" "DESTINATION" --recursive=false' \;`